# Orientation density plot (matplotlib)

Tags: python, math, matplotlib, plot, statistics

I have a large set of vectors, which orientations I want to analyze by looking at the polar angles theta and phi. So I start with a 2D array of those angles.

I want to visualize it by plotting a histogram, or preferentially the kernel density onto a sphere (or the 2D projection, since I only need the show half a sphere).

If I use the polar angles for the histogram, it will be completely wrong, since - to give an example - the points theta = 1°, phi = 0° & 180° are closer than theta = 30°, phi = 0° & 180°. The binning fails.

If I use 2D cartesian coordinates of the projection for the histogram, I run into the same problem: points on x = 0, y = 0 & 0.1 are closer than x = 0, y = 0.5 & 0.6.

Right now I'm using a kernel density estimate with 3D cartesian coordinates:

```
from scipy import stats

X, Y, Z = [], [], []
for i in range(300):
    for j in range(500):
        X.append(np.sin(i / 300 * pi / 2) * np.cos(j / 500 * 2 * pi))
        Y.append(np.sin(i / 300 * pi / 2) * np.sin(j / 500 * 2 * pi))
        Z.append(np.cos(i / 300 * pi / 2))
X, Y, Z = np.array(X), np.array(Y), np.array(Z)
positions = np.vstack([X, Y, Z])
# x, y and z for my data: sin(theta) * cos(phi), sin(theta) * sin(phi), cos(theta)
values = np.vstack([np.sin(data[:, 1]) * np.cos(data[:, 2]), np.sin(data[:, 1]) * np.sin(data[:, 2]), np.cos(data[:, 1])])

fig, ax = subplots(1, figsize=(7, 7))

kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
density = kernel(positions)

ax.tricontourf(X, Y, density, levels=np.linspace(0, max(density), 50))
plt.box('off')
ax.set_ylim((-1.01, 1.01))
ax.set_xlim((-1.01, 1.01))
```

This gives me:
[Polar density plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTaEY.png)

I don't know if a) this gives the correct result and b) if there isn't a better solution for this.

Comment: Can you provide some example data, so that your code can be run?